# Generate self-contained assembly subroutines with call to Windows API functions from C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, assembly, compilation

I have done some experiments with shellcode execution in which I wrote my own shellcode, write it into the target program's memory in which I want it executed and execute it with either a new thread or thread hijacking.

This works well, but manually writing the shellcode is rather time consuming, therefore I am looking for a method to be able to write a function in C or C++ that will be completely self-contained once compiled. This means that any compiled function should be executable independently. This way I could directly write it into my target's program ready to execute with WriteProcessMemory for example. Pushing the shellcode would therefore be done with a code like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

BOOL MakeABeep() {
    return Beep(0x500, 0x500);
}
DWORD MakeABeepEnd() { return 0; }

int main() {
    DWORD pid = 0;
    cout << "PID: ";
    cin >> dec >> pid;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    if (!hProcess) { cout << "OpenProcess failed GLE = " << dec << GetLastError() << endl; return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    void* buf = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 4096, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!buf) { cout << "VirtualAllocEx failed GLE = " << dec << GetLastError() << endl; return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    SIZE_T size = (DWORD64)MakeABeep - (DWORD64)MakeABeepEnd;
    BOOL wpmStatus = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, buf, MakeABeep, size, NULL);
    if (!wpmStatus) { cout << "WriteProcessMemory failed GLE = " << dec << GetLastError() << endl; return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)buf, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (!hThread) { cout << "CreateRemoteThread failed GLE = " << dec << GetLastError() << endl; return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, buf, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If compiled with the default options of MSVC compiler, only a bunch of `jmp` instructions are copied, which seem to be a jump table. To avoid this problem, I disabled incremental linking in the compiler options and now any code in the function `MakeABeep` is properly copied, with the exception of calls to imported functions.

In my shellcode I pass the arguments as required by the calling convention and then I put the address of the function I want to call in the register `rax` and finally I call the function with `call rax`.

Is it possible to make the compiler generate something like that? 
The key thing is that the generated binary has to have self-contained-only subroutines that could be executed independently.

For example, this is the assembly code generated for the function MakeABeep:
[image: MakeABeep Assembly code]
To be able to run it directly, instead of this `mov rax, QWORD PTR [rip+0x?]` the compiler should mov the full address of the Beep function into rax instead.

Please ignore the problems related to the modules possibly not loaded or loaded at a different address in the target program, I only intent to call functions in kernel32 and ntdll which are for sure loaded and at the same address in different processes.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I honestly thing that you will have better luck by compiling the code on the fly yourself (using some backend libraries, for example). Compilers are under no obligation to generate function code as written, and I do not think you can rely on your ability to force compiler to do what you want.

Comment: This is how imports often work.  There's only one relocation address that needs to be updated on module load, and the machine code bytes are unmodified (which can help with virtual memory paging).  There's no guarantee that `MakeABeepEnd` will be located right after `MakeABeep`.

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to just inject a trivial stub which loads a DLL. Every backend can generate a DLL with standard conventions, `GetProcAddress` will deal with the call setup, and relocations for the DLL are also handled.

Comment: Beware that `MakeABeepEnd()` isn't necessarily directly after `MakeABeep()` in the final executable. And why don't you GetProcAddress() all the functions you need, put these function pointers into a struct, copy this struct into the target application memory, and give it your injection function as the argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not know the full address of the Beep function. The Beep function lives in kernel32.dll and this .DLL is marked as [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) compatible and could in theory change its address every time you run the program. There is no compiler feature that lets you generate the real address of a function in a .DLL because such a feature is pretty useless.

One option I can think of is to use magic cookies that you replace with the correct function addresses at run time:

```
SIZE_T beepaddr = 0xff77ffffffff7001ull; // Magic value
((BOOL(WINAPI*)(DWORD,DWORD))beepaddr)(0x500, 0x500); // Call Beep()
```

compiles to

```
00011   b9 00 05 00 00   mov     ecx, 1280      ; 00000500H
00016   48 b8 01 70 ff ff ff ff 77 ff    mov     rax, -38280596832686079    ; ff77ffffffff7001H
00020   8b d1        mov     edx, ecx
00022   ff d0        call    rax
```

You would then have to write a wrapper around `WriteProcessMemory` that knows how to lookup and replace these magic values with the correct address.

Some shell code will have its own mini implementation of `GetModuleHandle` and `GetProcAddress` where it looks up the module in the PEB module list and then searches the export directory. They often use a mini hashing function for the names so they don't have to deal with strings.

If you are injecting a large amount of code you will probably get tired of these hacks and just load a .DLL in the remote process like everyone else.

Comment: Thank you so much Anders, this is simply perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.